# Cast between two slightly different std::map

Tags: c++, casting, stl, callback, stdmap

I have a std::map defined as follows:

```
typedef void (SomeClass::*callback_f)();

typedef std::pair<std::string, callback_f> my_pair;

typedef std::map<char,my_pair> my_map1;
```

There are multiple of these definitions, so there is my_map1, my_map2, etc. and every one of them differs from the other for the class SomeClass, which is SomeClass, SomeClassTwo, etc.

My need is to *pass all these maps to a single function*, which must have a single signature regardless of the maps, so I defined a generic map:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string ,void(*)(void)> my_generic_pair;
typedef std::map<char, my_generic_pair> my_generic_map;
```

And a function which takes it as a parameter:

```
void myGenericFunction(my_generic_map lmap);
```

**myGenericFunction** *doesn't* really use the callback, but uses the other two values from the **my_map{$i},   i=1...n**.

The problem is no matter how hard I try to cast between the two maps, the compiler (C++11 compliant GCC) always complains.

**Any ideas would be very much appreciated.**

Comment: A function template as generic function?

Comment: Have you tried templatizing the second argument to the pair<>.

Comment: After your suggestions I tried declaring the generic function as a function template as follows:
`template <typename T>
    void myGenericFunction(std::map<char, std::pair<char,T(*)()> > lst);`
but I receive a "_no matching function call for..void myGenericFunction(specific map)..candidate is..myGenericFunction void (generic map)_"

I can't get to declare the second pair element as `T::void(*)()` because I get a "_template argument is invalid_" error.

Comment: Aside: unless `myGenericFunction` really needs a deep copy of the map, you should take `lmap` by [`const`] reference/`&`, or even `&&` if wanting to take ownership and mutate it while the caller doesn't need to retain their copy....

Comment: Hi Tony yes, I'll most definitely take a const reference, thanks. I did not try to add that yet as I'm still struggling writing the signature.

Comment: *"I tried ... `T(*)()`"* - pointers to non-member functions are necessarily distinct types from pointers to member functions... I suggest you try matb's solution 1 which leaves the template free to substitute the caller-provided type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to pass all the maps to a single function, then all the maps must be exactly the same type (but you already knew that).

A little re-engineering should give you what you want.

Rather than define your map to hold a specific function pointer signature, simply define one map type that holds a polymorphic callable object - such an object is the std::function<>.

full compilable example (remember to enable c++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <map>

// callback_f is any callable that takes no parameters
typedef std::function<void()> callback_f;
typedef std::pair<std::string, callback_f> my_pair;

typedef std::map<char,my_pair> universal_map;

using namespace std;

struct SomeClass {
    static void callme_for_all() {
        cout << "SomeClass Hears You";
    }
};

struct SomeOtherClass {
    SomeOtherClass(string name)
    : _name { move(name) }
    {}

    void callme_for_each() const {
        cout << "I am called " << _name;
    }

private:
    string _name;    
};

void handle_map(const universal_map& m) {
    for (const auto& item : m) {
        cout << item.first << ":" << item.second.first << ":";
        item.second.second();
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   SomeClass a,b,c;

   SomeOtherClass x { "x" }, y { "y" }, z { "z" };

   universal_map map_someclass {
       { 'A', { "chicken", std::bind(&SomeClass::callme_for_all) } },
       { 'B', { "donkey", std::bind(&SomeClass::callme_for_all) } },
       { 'C', { "turkey", std::bind(&SomeClass::callme_for_all) } },
   };

   universal_map map_someotherclass {
       { 'A', { "pig", std::bind(&SomeOtherClass::callme_for_each, &x) } },
       { 'B', { "cat", std::bind(&SomeOtherClass::callme_for_each, &y) } },
       { 'C', { "dog", std::bind(&SomeOtherClass::callme_for_each, &z) } },
   };

   cout << "map for SomeClass - calling static methods" << endl;
   handle_map(map_someclass);
   cout << endl;

   cout << "map for SomeOtherClass - calling instance methods" << endl;
   handle_map(map_someotherclass);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer is very complete and adds flexibility compared to all others, but does the use of `std::bind`, `std::function` add any burden compared to matb's solution?

Comment: @FrancisStraccia if anything it reduces the maintenance burden because you don't need to maintain the enum. It will be no slower than the enum solution, and possibly faster.

Comment: Marking as answer for superior flexibility.

Comment: yes of course compared to the enum one, I meant in regards to Solution 1, the plain function template.

Comment: My thinking was as follows: you wrote "My need is to pass all these maps to a *single function*" [emphasis mine]. And of course a template-function is not a function, it's instructions on how to build a function when needed. So if you call the same template-function twice but with different types, you actually get two functions generated for you (with, for example, different addresses). The template solution will of course work, but I think on balance using type-erasure (std::function) will offer you more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
template<typename T>
void myGenericFunction(std::map < char, std::pair < std::string, T > > lmap);
```

Solution 2 (only if you can't use templates and overloading for whatever reason):

```
enum MapType {MY_MAP1, MY_MAP2, ...};
void myGenericFunction(void* lmap, MapType typeOfLmap)
{
    switch(typeOfLmap)
    {
        case MY_MAP1:
            //do something with ((my_map1*)lmap)
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: edited according to @TonyD's suggestion.

Comment: "Solution 2" (swtich on discrimination enum param) isn't worthy of mention, as it's more verbose, cluttered, inefficient and error prone than writing out distinct overloads.

Comment: @TonyD Right, overloading is better in any situation where it's adequate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control on your SomeClass, SomeClass2..., you can use inheritance to solve this problem:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
  virtual ~BaseClass(){}
  virtual void f() = 0;
};
class SomeClass : public BaseClass {...};
class SomeClass2 : public BaseClass {...};

typedef void (BaseClass::*callback_f)();
....
```

Comment: I actually have no control over them, but if I had this would have been a nice solution.